# Build error after Angular upgrade - MediaQueryListEvent not assignable of type MediaQueryList

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-flex-layout, angular-material-6

I have upgraded my Angular version from 5.2 to 7.2.0 and using below versions of packages:

"**@angular/flex-layout**": "**^7.0.0-beta.22**", **typescript version** : **3.2.2**, "**@angular/cdk**" : **7.2.1**, "**@angular/cli** : **7.1.4**"

I getting a build error:

> 'MediaQueryListEvent' is not assignable of type MediaQueryList.

Code:

```
export class LayoutComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private _router: Subscription;

  mediaMatcher: MediaQueryList = matchMedia(`(max-width: ${SMALL_WIDTH_BREAKPOINT}px)`);
  url: string;
  sidePanelOpened;

  constructor (
    private _element: ElementRef,
    private router: Router) {
    this.mediaMatcher.addListener(mql => zone.run(() => {
      this.mediaMatcher = mql; //i am getting error here Type 'MediaQueryListEvent' is not assignable to type 'MediaQueryList'.
                  //Property 'onchange' is missing in type 'MediaQueryListEvent'.
    }));
  }
 }
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi you can try changing this line

```
zone.run(() => this.mediaMatcher = mql));
```

for this

```
zone.run(() => this.mediaMatcher = matchMedia(`(max-width: ${SMALL_WIDTH_BREAKPOINT}px)`)));
```

Comment: Do we know why this issue is happening, as to the root cause? Glad the line above fixed it, but not clear as to why the parameter that is passed in now is `MediaQueryListEvent` and not `MediaQueryList`.

Comment: Hi, the reason fot this issue i dont know, just i read the documentation and saw this
https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/overview